# Bash script not working with ffmpeg + images

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I created a bash file with the name "run.sh" with the following instructions:

```
ffmpeg -i texture/texture%03d.bmp -vf "scale='min(1920,iw)':min'(1080,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" pad_texture/pad_texture%03d.bmp
ffmpeg -i depth/depth%03d.bmp -vf "scale='min(1920,iw)':min'(1080,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" ../pad_depth/pad_depth%03d.bmp
```

However, when I run my bash file I get the following error:

```
Input #0, image2, from 'texture/texture%03d.bmp':
  Duration: 00:00:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgr24, 1024x768, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[NULL @ 0x1defec0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pad_texture/pad_'exture%03d.bmp
: Invalid argumentxture%03d.bmp
```

I cannot understand why when I copy and paste the commands line by line into the command prompt, they are accepted, but in a bash script they are not. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure that your `run.sh` doesn't contains some unprintable characters? like `\r` or some escape-sequences or such... `cat -vet run.sh` could help to check.

Comment: no, nothing of the sort... just those 2 commands right there

Comment: Is the error from the first command? You can temporary delete the second. 
Try with another inputfile. `cp pad_texture/pad_texture%03d.bmp pad_texture/so_test.bmp` and try the command with `pad_texture/so_test.bmp`.

Comment: Are you running the bash script in bourne shell or bash mode? I.e. does the hashbang line look like: `#! /bin/sh` or `#! /bin/bash` ?